# skip buffered packets while decoding

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libav

I've got a `Server` that encodes live data and sends it as `AVPacket`s, a `Client` decodes (`H.264`) and previews the data.
Sometimes because of connectivity issues the packets don't arrive at all, get buffered and the `Client` gets multiple at the same time.
[image]

Now if the `Client` decodes all the buffered packets and such gaps repeat multiple times,
the lag keeps growing and the stream is no longer live.

The priority is to keep the stream live over quality and discontinuities.

- is it allowed to manually skip an `AVPacket` while decoding?
- is there an option to tell the `Decoder` to discard packets that are old *(maybe old `timestamp`)*?
- any other options?

Comment: Use av_gettime_relative to measure the drift between packet pts and real time and drop packet before feeding to decoder depending on latency.  Expect some artifacts for frames with missing refs. Don't drop keyframes (drop following packets).

Comment: @Gyan By keyframes you mean packets with flag `AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY`? and could you please elaborate on what are `refs`.

Comment: Yes & refs = reference frames. If a ref is dropped, then all frames that depend on that ref will have artifacts.

Comment: @Gyan thanks, I solved it by making all my frames as intra frames (`AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I`) and assumption that for every intra frame I get only one `AVPacket`, is it a right assumption to make? which means I can discard any packet because none of them are part of reference frames and get no artifacts.

Comment: If the encoder is slice threaded, then that's not a safe assumption. Check first.